# ANOVA: compares means among 3 models or linear vs simpler model?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, anova, t-test, f-test

So I'm super confused. Looking online for example:[here](https://www.edanzediting.com/blogs/statistics-anova-explained) or [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analysis_of_variance) or [here](https://statistics.laerd.com/statistical-guides/one-way-anova-statistical-guide.php) or in any other website I could find ANOVA is " used to determine whether there are any statistically significant differences between the means of three or more independent (unrelated) groups" or "are useful for comparing (testing) three or more means (groups or variables) for statistical significance" or "ANOVA is used to compare differences of means among more than 2 groups.".

However I'm studying linear regression models and both in simple and in multiple linear regression, our lecturer uses ANOVA in a totally different way!

We use ANOVA to compare the linear regression model (where response depends linearly on explanatory variable) with the simpler "constant" model where there is no relationship between response and explanatory variable. (and similarly for multiple linear regression we compare whether we need $p>q$ explanatory variables or only $q$ are enough)

> Hence is my lecturer teaching us something wrong? Are they two different types of ANOVA but with the same name? Or are they the same thing and I don't see the connection?

**EDIT**

Here is what the lecture notes say for simple linear regression (similar for multiple):
[image: anova]
[image: anova2]

Comment: Yes you would never use ANOVA that way.  You can even use it for two groups where the two sample t test is a special case.

Comment: @MichaelChernick wait is the Yes to "my lecturer is wrong"?

Comment: No. Your lecturer is correct. Your lecturer was doing ANOVA table comparison. https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/anova.html

Comment: To be completely clear the yes is with reference to your lecturer being wrong.

Comment: @SleepWithStatistics your two answers are opposite, so this is very confusing

Comment: @MichaelChernick I think the lecturer is right. We can use ANOVA table for comparing two models?

Comment: @Euler_Salter No, they are the same thing.

Comment: @SleepWithStatistics you saying my lecturer is correct and MichaelChernick saying my lecturer is right are the same thing? What is going on here..

Comment: I am quite sure that I am right and @SleepWithStatistics is wrong.  Just look at any reputable link such as the ones you mentioned.

Comment: @MichaelChernick the fact that ANOVA is used for comparing the means surely must be correct as can be seen by those sources. My concern was whether the way it is used by my lecturer can be seen as equivalent as that problem.

Comment: @Euler_Salter ANOVA tables are used for comparing linear models. There are sources all over the Internet. Whether your lecturer actually meant that, ask him!

Comment: @SleepWithStatistics currently he is away and not answering to emails for the past days so I can't get any help out of him

Comment: @SleepWithStatistics so then is there a difference between ANOVA and ANOVA tables?

Comment: @Euler_Salter Add his lecture notes to the question. Give us some more reference.

Comment: This is too much discussion for a simple issue. The lecturer probably doesn't know that he is wrong and won't believe it when we tell him.

Comment: @SleepWithStatistics I will add them. Is there a way to add pdf files?

Comment: @SleepWithStatistics I've edited the question and added two screenshots of the lecture notes, hope you can read them

Comment: Since you are so confident in your correctness, @Michael, then please be so kind as to post an actual answer.  This will enable you to supply your reasoning, to explain what interpretation of the question underlies it, and let the community comment on and evaluate it.  Absent such support for your opinions, I would warmly encourage Euler_Salter and others to ignore this comment thread completely.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're talking about is just the definition for ANOVA. Remember:

- ANOVA is used to *"determine whether there are any statistically significant differences between the means of three or more independent (unrelated) groups"*. That's in your question, good.
- **To do that**, ANOVA partitions the variation between groups as "regression sum of squares".
- **To do that**, ANOVA also partitions the variation within groups as "residual sum of squares".
- That's why you see "Regression" and "Residual" source in your lecture notes.
- We then use the F-test to compare "Regression" and "Residual" as a **ratio**. If the ratio is too large, we conclude there is significant difference in group effects.

Your lecturer was correct. In fact, it was just the definition for ANOVA. There is no contradiction, we're talking about the same thing.

My answer is not very mathematical, because I know you're asking for easy explanation (e.g. I skip degrees of freedom). If you're looking for more precise explanation, head to:

> https://onlinecourses.science.psu.edu/stat414/node/218